# AS3 not passing number by value, rather by reference?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var newChoice:MainButton = new MainButton(function(){
     trace(this["func" + i])} );
}

public function func0 ...
public function func1 ...
public function func2 ...
```

(When clicked, MainButton calls the function in the argument)

However, I get func3, which I assume is do to it finding the value of i. But shouldn't it pass by value since it's a number? How do I get the wanted result? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not passing anything, except the function itself (which is passed by reference).

What's happening is that the function creates a closure around the variable `i`, changing its lifetime. When the anonymous function is called, `i` is still in its original scope, but the loop has already finished, leaving `i` at 3.

So, the closure is essentially keeping `i` in the scope of the function even after the original, declaring function has finished.

Instead of closing over the variable, you wanted to close over the variable's *value* at the time the function is created. You can achieve this with an intermediate variable that's set only once before being closed over:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var j = i;       // New variable each time through the loop; closure will close over a different variable each time (that happens to have the same name)
    var newChoice:MainButton = new MainButton(function(){
        trace(this["func" + j])} );
}
```

Comment: Be warned closures can be hell on garbage collection. Closures are basically objects that have lost scope and because of that are very hard for the system to GC them, but +1 for giving a decent solution and explanation.